# SQLite: LIKE clause won't work with DELETE

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I was trying to delete rows in a table using the like clause, the query doesn't produce an error but the query doesn't delete the rows.

```
cur.execute("DELETE FROM urls WHERE url LIKE 'https%';")
```

Meanwhile the query to select the same works.

```
cur.execute("SELECT url FROM urls WHERE url LIKE 'https%';")
```

Comment: Read the official Python sqlite3 docs and do tutorials!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to commit DML queries with `con.commit()`.

PS: You need to label Python code with `Python` tag.